# Fatal error with WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, php

I just did a fresh install of WP 3.5, trying to use the Uraniumoid theme by Padd Solutions and boom, getting the fatal error

```
Call to undefined method Padd_Twitter::SimplePie() in on line in /home/fxmypics/public_html/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php on line 3042
```

I investigated and see that "Padd_Twitter" is called in `class-twitter.php`, `defaults.php`, `functions.php` inside `Uraniumoid\includes` folder but I don't know how to fix it, some help?

Comment: This question belongs on [wordpress answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) - it is a question about using WP, not writing code for it.

Answer (score 0):

For those that couldn't find the solution, this has worked for me:

In the file class-twitter.php:

- Replace "**$this->SimplePie();**" on line 56 approximately with: "**parent::__construct();**"
- In line 59 approximately, replace: 
  **$this->set_feed_url('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/' . $username . '.rss');**
  with: **$this->set_feed_url('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.rss?screen_name=' . $username . '');**

It worked for me